# h2-console does not show up

Tags: spring-boot, h2

In my spring boot application, I have added the below dependencies:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.196</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

and then in my `application.properties` i set:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
management.security.enabled=false
```

But when i navigate to the uri:

```
http://localhost:8080/h2-console/login.do?jsessionid=cfc3b5595b531203d92134205e16127e
```

It complains with:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

    Wed Sep 27 03:37:52 GMT-12:00 2017
    There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
    No message available
```

***Why don't i have access to*** `h2-console`?

Comment: Do you have `spring.datasource.url` in your `application.properties`?

Comment: I entered the console today earlier, but now I'm having the same error.

Comment: having same error too

Answer (score 2):

There is one possible reason why `h2-console` show that error. That is your files may not be organized in right way. I've also fetched this problem when I keep my Controller, Service, Repository and Model files all together in one package.

I've solved this problem by organizing them separately in their own packages like below

`com.example.demo.controller`
`com.example.demo.service`
`com.example.demo.repository`
`com.example.demo.model`

My application.properties file contains

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following configuration class in your project and try again.

```
import org.h2.server.web.WebServlet;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializer;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.filter.ShallowEtagHeaderFilter;

import javax.servlet.DispatcherType;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import java.util.EnumSet;

@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration {

    private static final String mapping = "/console/*";

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean h2servletRegistration(){
        ServletRegistrationBean registrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean( new WebServlet());
        registrationBean.addUrlMappings(mapping);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean shallowEtagHeaderFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registration.setFilter(new ShallowEtagHeaderFilter());
        registration.setDispatcherTypes(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));
        registration.addUrlPatterns(mapping);
        return registration;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletContextInitializer initializer() {
        return new ServletContextInitializer() {

            @Override
            public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
                servletContext.setInitParameter("p-name", "-value");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case commenting out spring security from application.properties allowed me to see h2 console again(restart to see the effect)-->

ex. #spring.security.user.name=kk
    #spring.security.user.password=password